Is there a way to search the woocommerce order notes in the orders dashboard
I have a e-commerce site that uses a local courier company's woocommerce plugin, it sends the waybill number to the order notes, I want to search for these waybill numbers on the regular orders dashboard like I would search for a name of a product.
Is there a way to extend the search functionality to also search through the order notes to pick up this waybill number?
I tried adding the waybill number to the order name, but this got messy as they can be different formats each time
I'd rather just be able to search it normally
